# sending a Email without SMTP Service on android?

Tags: android, email, smtp, export

I am creating a csv file in my app which I have to send to an user.

But I want to send the email with the attachment *without* using a *SMTP SERVER or SERVICE*. 
I cant use Intents, which excludes preinstalled Email Apps.

Is it possible or not? If not Why?

Comment: Without your app actually being what is sending the email (which would require an SMTP server,relay, or service) you can use Intent.ACTION_SEND and then you can pass your attachement.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to say, that i also cant use an intent with a app chooser

Comment: Then no it is not really going to be possible. If you can't launch the mail apps and you can't use an SMTP server how in the world are you going to send emails?

Comment: could you also explain me, why this is impossible?

Comment: Sending emails requires the use of an SMTP server, plain and simple. You might want to lookup how emails work before getting to far ahead of yourself.